# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: error: the NULL value in the "id" column for "avatar" indicates the value NOT NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: error: the NULL value in the "id" column for "avatar" indicates the value NOT NULL   Specifications: The additional string contains (null, 16508, avatars\2.jpg , 150, image/jpeg, 2).
```

When I try to add an avatar for a student by id > 1, I get an error. If id = 1 then everything works fine.
Also in the error message there is a link to this line:
avatarRepository.save(avatar);
allegedly a mistake here
However, I don't understand how to figure out what needs to be fixed.
below I will give the code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("avatar")
public class AvatarController {
    private AvatarService avatarService;

    public AvatarController(AvatarService avatarService) {
        this.avatarService = avatarService;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/{studentId}/avatar", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadAvatar(@PathVariable Long studentId, @RequestParam MultipartFile avatar) throws IOException {
        avatarService.uploadAvatar(studentId, avatar);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}



@Service
@Transactional
public class AvatarService {

    @Value("${path.to.avatars.folder}")
    private String avatarsDir;

    private final AvatarRepository avatarRepository;
    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;

    public AvatarService(AvatarRepository avatarRepository, StudentRepository studentRepository) {
        this.avatarRepository = avatarRepository;
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }

    public void uploadAvatar(Long studentId, MultipartFile avatarFile) throws IOException {
        Optional<Student> optionalStudent = studentRepository.findById(studentId);//получаем студента по id
        if (optionalStudent.isPresent() && avatarFile == null) { //проверяем что не получили ноль
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        Student student = optionalStudent.orElse(null); //извлекаем студента из обертки Optional
        String originalFileName = avatarFile.getOriginalFilename();//получаем имя файла аватарки

        if (originalFileName == null) { //проверяем что имя аватарки действительно получено
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        //формируем путь к файлу аватарки - путь + имя файла + расширение
        Path filePath = Path.of(avatarsDir, studentId + getExtensions(originalFileName));
        Files.createDirectories(filePath.getParent());
        Files.deleteIfExists(filePath);
        //создаем потоки исходящий и входящий, а так же буферизированные на их основе
        try (
                InputStream is = avatarFile.getInputStream();//открываем поток из аватарки MultipartFile
                OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(filePath, CREATE_NEW);//
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 1024);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os, 1024);
        ) {
            bis.transferTo(bos); //подаем входящий поток в исходящий, записывая аватарку с КП в БД
        }
        Avatar avatar = findAvatar(studentId);//получаем аватар по id студента
        avatar.setStudent(student);// присваиваем в аватар id студента
        avatar.setFilePath(filePath.toString()); //путь к файлу
        avatar.setFileSize(avatarFile.getSize()); //размер файла
        avatar.setMediaType(avatarFile.getContentType()); //тип файла
        avatar.setData(avatarFile.getBytes()); //размер файла
        avatarRepository.save(avatar); //сохраняем в БД
    }
}



public interface AvatarRepository extends JpaRepository<Avatar, Long> {
    Optional<Avatar> findAvatarByStudentId(Long studentId);
}



@Entity
public class Avatar {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private  String filePath;
    private  long fileSize;
    private  String mediaType;

    @Lob
    private  byte[] data;

    @OneToOne
    private Student student;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFilePath() {
        return filePath;
    }

    public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    public long getFileSize() {
        return fileSize;
    }

    public void setFileSize(long fileSize) {
        this.fileSize = fileSize;
    }

    public String getMediaType() {
        return mediaType;
    }

    public void setMediaType(String mediaType) {
        this.mediaType = mediaType;
    }

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }
}
```

Tell me what you need to do so that the avatar is added not only by id 1

Comment: Is that the exact text? or an approximation? If the latter, please replace with the real text, via cut and paste.

Comment: https://github.com/Liuban0Stanislav/HomeWork3.1/pull/6/files#diff-d173e6d56e9cbf9004cbde1e9beac93ddacc1d4ea6a7b0b1b32778f3429087a8

Comment: If you mean the whole code, then there it is

Comment: I mean the error message.

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: error: the NULL value in the "id" column for "avatar" indicates the value NOT NULL
  Features: An additional string contains (null, 16510, avatars\2.jpg , 150, image/jpeg, 2).

Comment: Is it really 'indicates'? And are you trying to set NULL into a column that is defined as NOT NULL?